# Unity how to show game object in other class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to show a game object from another class in unity.

I have a game object called loader in shopdialog class:
[image]

[image]

```
   public class ShopDialog : Dialog
{
   public GameObject loader;
}
```

Now I want to show this game object from another class. I have tried to call `ShopDialog.loader.SetActive(true);`in the other class.
but it gives me this error:

**Assets/WordGame/Scripts/Purchaser.cs(174,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShopDialog.loader'**

Does anyone know what I can do to show this game object? Or should I do it in another way?

Comment: did you assign loader? variables dont assign themselves

Comment: How can I do that? Do you mean like the new image I posted?

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you:

You need an **instance** of that `ShopDialog` class ... currently you are trying to directly go through the type itself which would only work if your field was `static`. You need e.g. a field

```
public ShopDialog shopDialogInstance;
```

and then you can do

```
shopDialogInstance.loader.SetActive(true);
```

there is many different ways of how to get the instance exactly depending a lot on your use case, either using [`FindFirstObjectByType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindFirstObjectByType.html), [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), or one of their variants - or by as said have a field and assign it via drag and drop through the Inspector

Comment: Thank you. But this gives me error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @MatKoffman well then probably you didn't assign any reference to the according field/variable... Tbh I think you might want to go through some basic c# tutorials before jumping into Unity. This is a very basic "issue"/question

Comment: okay thank you.